# profile the exact time spent in executing each line of a C++ code

Tags: c++, xcode, valgrind

how to profile the exact time spent in executing each line of a C++ code, the code is currently running on Xcode Version 9.0.1 ?

Comment: you can use gprof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to determine the exact time because with an optimizing compiler, there is no exact correspondence between source lines and the executed machine code.  Some source lines do not produce any separate machine code at all (because their effects are folded into other instructions), and other source lines generate multiple instructions which are interleaved with instructions from other source lines, due to optimizations such as instruction scheduling.